# jQuery: live change event on IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, jquery

I have capture change event on drop down select. This drop down field is created using AJAX so event capture need to be done with live or bind.
Here I add the code which I'm using currently. This is working on fire fox. On IE7 its not working. Can anyone tell me a way to capture live event of drop down select on IE7

```
    <select id="lob_drop" name="opt" class="select">
       <option value="1">option 1</option>
       <option value="2">option 2</option>
       <option value="3">option 3</option>
    </select>

    jQuery('#lob_drop').live('change',function(){
       alert(jQuery('#lob_drop option:selected').val());
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jquery `.on()`. `.live()` is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '#lob_drop', function(){
       alert(jQuery('#lob_drop option:selected').val());
   }
);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D8FaU/)

Answer (score 1):

What is your JQuery version ?

It works for me on IE7 using JQuery 1.4+
It seems live() wouldn't work with change event in IE in all previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
$('body').on('change', '#lob_drop', function(){
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

Here's a fiddle with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/7EcGE/24/

My previous suggestion below won't work since [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated an removed since jQuery 1.9:

```
jQuery('#lob_drop').live('change',function(){
   alert(jQuery(this).val());
});
```